# What is the `passiveSupported ? { passive: true } : false` called?

Tags: javascript, syntax

From:

```
someElement.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp, passiveSupported
                               ? { passive: true } : false);
```

What is the `passiveSupported ? { passive: true } : false` called? The question mark and colon. I understand what it is doing, I just want to know what it is called so I can Google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most languages, this is usually referred to as the **ternary operator**. Here's [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) as it pertains to Javascript in particular.